# How do I load the InterOP.ActiveDs on my Windows Server 2008R2?

Tags: c#, active-directory

My application runs perfectly from my Windows 10 machine on the domain, however when I run the app in the server I get the following error `The system cannot the file specified.  File name: "InterOp.ActiveDs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

I have tried various solutions but none seems to be working for me.  Have also tried this one https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5a92a204-81fe-4c6f-bfc3-ef04dc932ed0/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-interopactiveds-version1000-cultureneutral?forum=netfx64bit But still not working

[image: Attached Image:]

Comment: You just forgot to copy the file.  Select the ActiveDs reference in your project and ensure that its Copy Local property is True.  Verify that Interop.ActiveDs.dll appears in the project's bin\Release directory.  Copy everything from that directory.

Comment: Try referencing the same from `C:\Windows\System32\Activeds.tlb` by modifying the code, and then check if it works! Surprisingly, I've also started receiving the error since today, and had to modify it as per my comment!